# php javascript form question variable isnt passing

Tags: php, javascript, forms

http://dev.icalapp.rogersdigitalmedia.com.rogers-test.com/Edit.php

When I enter numbers into that list and click submit it won't display the array of numbers in something.php.....

I am really confused as to what the problem is....

Here is the code for it:

http://pastebin.com/a2nZqmGW

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must give the new input a name, not an id.

```
newGuy.setAttribute("name", 'number'+numberOfNumbers);
or
newGuy.setAttribute("name", 'numbers[]');//will create an array in php for $_GET['numbers']
```

Comment: i found the problem, it was the form action thingy....it was missing a method to post the data....so after I put method= POST it started working with your phone array, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

When you create the inputs that contain the numbers, they don't have a name. Therefore, they don't get passed via GET or POST to your something.php file, so you can't output them in an array. You need to give each input a unique name attribute when they are created.

Also, it would be helpful if you provided the something.php source, but I'm pretty sure it's the input name issue.

Comment: my something.php is: <?php

It is still not worknig after I tried what Gerben said....I tried both of them by replacing the newGuy.setAttribute("id", numberOfNumbers); by the line he gave and I tried both all I get is Array() for +numberOfNumbers and for the numbers[] I get php compiling error..
 
print_r ($_POST);


?>